# Augmenting set of project output files in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

Is it possible in MSBuild 4.0 and/or 4.5 to specify additional files to be treated as a manifest output of a project by its dependencies, and copied with the binary project output, whenever that is copied? Ideally, I want to create some files beside a .dll during build, and would like these files to stay in the same folder as the .dll whenever it is copied to a directory of a project depending on it.

If this is not clear, I am thinking of .pdb and documentation .xml files created by the C# compiler. These files treated specially: Whenever another project requests the .dll be copied locally into its binary directory, these files go with the .dll. Can I augment this set with my own special files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, and here is why. Actually, there is no concept of project output accessible externally *between* MSBuild projects. Rather, when a reference to a project is added, the SDK-provided build framework (based on MSBuild scripts) looks for a few specific files matching the name of the referenced DLL, and copies these files with the DLL itself into the current project output directory (assuming `CopyLocal` is set, which is probably true for a referenced project).

In framework v4.0, this is done by the task `ResolveAssemblyReference` which is called from an identically named target from the file `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets`. The task looks for specially named files placed beside the target DLL, including its matchin PDB files and an XML documentation file. Other files are also discovered, as I infer from the decompiled source.

So nothing in a given project specifically marks these files as somehow "exported" from the project. The magic happens on the pulling side.